How does this industrial camera's digital input circuit work?
Industrial cameras I use have a GPIO pin which looks like this when used as an input:

Source:
https://docs.baslerweb.com/circuit-diagrams-(basler-cameras)#gpio-input-line
I'm curious about how it works, because I can't figure it out with my limited electronics knowledge. Could anyone point me in the right direction maybe?
Digital zero is 0-0.8 V, one is 2-5 V, absolute maximum voltage 30 V. From experience, it seems like it can survive 24 V indefinitely without damage, but it refused to work when we accidentally tried to trigger the camera using a 24 V PLC output. The camera didn't register the edges -- either never seeing a zero or a one. At first I suspected that it didn't react to signal edges because the voltage wasn't dropping low enough but the multimeter says the voltage dropped to ~0.4 V.
Another curious detail. The docs say:

Input current (high-level): <100 μA
Input current (low-level): <5 mA sink current from the GPIO input line without exceeding 0.8 VDC.

Does this mean it's acting as a current source when shorted to 0 V? That would make sense looking at the schematic as there's then a path from the internal 3.3 V to zero through some resistance and a diode.

If you apply a high voltage (higher than 2.0VDC according to the documentation) then the amount of current flowing from the 3.3V supply into the logic gate will be either zero or "small".  The voltage drop across the top resistor will then be insufficient to turn on the transistor in the input buffer and the FPGA input will be low.  Note that if the input voltage is higher than 3.3V then the Schottky diode will mostly prevent current flowing out of the external logic gate and into the 3.3V supply.  But there will be some reverse leakage through the diode and 100uA seems a plausible maximum (especially if hot).  Your experience indicates that up to 24V on the input is okay but the documentation suggests a 5V maximum for "safe" operation.  It is possible that operation above 5V for a long time will shorten the life of components.
If instead you apply a low voltage (0-0.8V according to the documentation) then the amount of current flowing through the top resistor and into the external logic gate will be high enough to turn on the transistor in the input buffer and the FPGA input will be pulled up to something close to 3.3V.  The two resistors will limit the current flowing into the output of the external gate.  It's a bit unclear but I think the documentation implies that your input gate should be capable of sinking up to 5mA of current while still outputting less than 0.8V when in the low state, in which case it follows that the resistors (and diode) will limit the current to no more than 5mA.

Thanks, seems to make sense, but what's that transistor/zener pair doing? Couldn't it be replaced by a simple resistor? And the zener diode seems completely useless as drawn. If its breakdown voltage is higher than the maximum input voltage, it may as well not be there. If the breakdown voltage is lower than the max, the diode will die because there's nothing in series to take the excess voltage and it'll effectively be a short.

I believe the transistor/Zener pair at the bottom is mostly for GPIO output.  The transistor does nothing when the GPIO is set to be an input, but the Zener will clamp the input in some cases.  For instance, if you put a negative voltage on the input the Zener will clamp it to about -0.6V, and if you put a positive voltage on the input that exceeds the breakdown it will clamp it at the breakdown voltage.  In either clamping case it will possibly make the Zener very hot if the voltage is applied for a non-trivial time; probably useful for transients/spikes but not so useful for mis-wiring.
